# Scrabble - the best move

Tags: math

I have made algorithm for scrabble . It uses strategy of highest score . But I do not think that is is the best way to play the game.

My question is: **is there any advanced math for scrabble that suggests not the highest score word but an other one  that will increase the probability to win**?

Or in other words some different strategy then highest  score?

I have my own ideas how it can be. For example, suppose there are two words that have almost the same score (s1 > s2) but lets say the second word does not open new way to 3W or 2W and even its score is less then the score of first one, than it is good to use the second word and not the first one.

Comment: Advanced math? You are kidding here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience with scrabble, you are correct in that you don't necessarily want to always suggest the highest scoring word. Rather, you want to suggest the **best** word. I don't think this requires a lot of advanced math to pull off.

Here are some suggestions:

- In your current algorithm, rank all your letters, particularly consonants, by ease of use. For example, the letter `"S"` would have the highest ease of use because it is the most flexible. That is, when you play a given word and leave out the letter `"S"`, you are essentially opening up the possibility for better word choices with the new letters than come into play on your next turn.
- Balance out vowel and consonant usage in your words. As a regular scrabble player, I don't always play the best scoring word if the best scoring word doesn't use enough vowels. For example, if I use 4 letters than contain no vowels and I have 3 vowels left in my array of letters, chances are I am going to draw at least two vowels on my next turn, which would leave me with 5 vowels and 2 consonants, which chances are doesn't open up a lot of opportunity for high scoring words. **It is almost always better to use more vowels than consonants in your words, especially the letter `I`. Your algorithm should reflect some of this when selecting the best word.**

I hope this gives you a good start. Once your algorithm is able to select the best scoring word, you can fine tune it with these suggestions in order to be an overall better scorer in your scrabble games. (I am assuming this is some sort of AI you are creating)

Comment: thanks, both are good ideas, I must try

Comment: Since you like ROFLwTIME's answer, give him some credit. It's how this site works.

Comment: I like his answer but I am new in stackoverflow and do not know how to give credit.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: is there any advanced math for scrabble that suggests not the highest score word but an other one that will increase the probability to win?

As ROFLwTIME mentioned, you need to also account for the letters that you haven't played.

In doing that accounting, you need to account for how letters interact with one another. For example, suppose you have a Q, a U, and five other letters. Suppose the best you can score playing both the Q and the U is 30 points, but you can score more by playing the U but leaving the Q unplayed. Unless that "more" is much more than 30, either play the word with the Q or find a third word that leaves both the Q and the U unplayed.

You also need to account for the opportunities the word you play creates for your opponents. A typical game theory strategy is to maximize your score while minimizing your opponents score, maximin for short. Playing a 20 point word that allows your opponent to play a 50 point word is not a good idea.

Comment: Good point. You definitely want to take into account that you may be opening up the opportunity for your opponent to play a word on a "Triple Word" tile. There are definitely a lot of things you can do to make a good scrabble AI.